# WPF Timeline Control End Time Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timeline

#### About

---

I have added a third party control to my application (*See Below*) :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240411/WPF-Timeline-Control-Part-I

This control had the functionality that i needed in my application like *Drag and Drop from a Listbox*, *Drag End Time*, *Drag Start Time* and *Move Slide*.

It uses 5 different C# Classes:

- TimeLineControl (*Handles the actual TimeLine e.g. Items_Changed, Draw Lines)*.
- TimeLineItemControl (*Handles the items inside the TimeLine e.g. Move_End, Move_Start)*.
- TempDataType (*Properties which the Items in the TimeLine are bound to e.g. End Time, Start Time*).

  ```
  public class TempDataType : ITimeLineDataItem
  {
      public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
      public ImageBrush BackgroundImage { get; set; }
      public Boolean TimelineViewExpanded { get; set; }
      public String Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- ITimeLineManager (*Not sure what this is actually used for*).

  ```
  public interface ITimeLineManager
  {
      Boolean CanAddToTimeLine(ITimeLineDataItem item);
  }
  ```
- ITimeLineDataItem (*Again I am not really sure what this is for*).

  ```
  public interface ITimeLineDataItem
  {
      TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
      TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
      Boolean TimelineViewExpanded { get; set; }
  }
  ```

#### What I want to achieve

---

The user will Drag a slide from the Listbox onto the Timeline. Then when the user clicks 'Play' my live camera feed will appear and the End Time of the slide will move real time with the time the camera has been live.

#### Issue

---

There seems to be buttons at the Start and End of a Item inside the TimeLineControl and these are defined here:

```
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PART_ContentHostPART_ContentHost" />
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PART_LeftIndicator">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <Button />
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
</ContentPresenter>
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PART_RightIndicator">
    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <Button />
    </ContentPresenter.Content>
 </ContentPresenter>
```

These already seem to have events linked to them so that if you Click or Move on a Item inside the TimelineControl something will get triggered.

When I debug the program to see what happens when I manually move the End, it seems to pass `object sender` to the method which get passed as:

[image]

Then it casts this to a TimeLineItemControl `TimeLineItemControl ctrl = sender as TimeLineItemControl;`

When I try and do this I can find the Item in the TimeLine but it will not let me cast as mine appears like this:

[image]

#### What I need to know

---

I want to know when I click the 'Play' button, how to do I get the End Time to move on the TimeLineControl real time.

*Sorry if I have missed some information out, let me know and I will add it straight in.*